# How do I get TinyMCE emoticons to use absolute URLs?

Tags: tinymce

The emoticons in my TinyMCE installation all use relative URLs such as "tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-cool.gif".

How do I tell TinyMCE to use absolute URLs such as "/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-cool.gif" instead? I have tried

```
  relative_urls : false,
  remove_script_host : false,
  convert_urls : true,
```

in `tinyMCE.init({ ... });`.

I have also tried using `document_base_url : "/",`, but none of these methods change the URLs of the emoticons.

Answer (score 0):

Just searched for answer on that, and managed that myself.

```
relative_urls: false,
document_base_url: '//yoururl.com/',
```

Maybe it will work with `document_base_url: '//',`